# SFTP in Python? (platform independent)

Tags: python, sftp

I'm working on a simple tool that transfers files to a hard-coded location with the password also hard-coded.  I'm a python novice, but thanks to ftplib, it was easy:

```
import ftplib

info= ('someuser', 'password')    #hard-coded

def putfile(file, site, dir, user=(), verbose=True):
    """
    upload a file by ftp to a site/directory
    login hard-coded, binary transfer
    """
    if verbose: print 'Uploading', file
    local = open(file, 'rb')    
    remote = ftplib.FTP(site)   
    remote.login(*user)         
    remote.cwd(dir)
    remote.storbinary('STOR ' + file, local, 1024)
    remote.quit()
    local.close()
    if verbose: print 'Upload done.'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    site = 'somewhere.com'            #hard-coded
    dir = './uploads/'                #hard-coded
    import sys, getpass
    putfile(sys.argv[1], site, dir, user=info)
```

The problem is that I can't find any library that supports sFTP.  What's the normal way to do something like this securely?

Edit:  Thanks to the answers here, I've gotten it working with Paramiko and this was the syntax.

```
import paramiko

host = "THEHOST.com"                    #hard-coded
port = 22
transport = paramiko.Transport((host, port))

password = "THEPASSWORD"                #hard-coded
username = "THEUSERNAME"                #hard-coded
transport.connect(username = username, password = password)

sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)

import sys
path = './THETARGETDIRECTORY/' + sys.argv[1]    #hard-coded
localpath = sys.argv[1]
sftp.put(localpath, path)

sftp.close()
transport.close()
print 'Upload done.'
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks ! Got an SFTP upload script working in 5 minutes :)

Comment: Just a general  note on original question  that python ftplib has also support for FTPS - ftp over TLS  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPS . FTPS servers are arguably less used in Unix world, partly due to omnipresence of ssh/sftp,however, sftp servers are much less present in Windows environment, where FTPS is more common.

Comment: Looks like FTPS support was added in Python 3.2 with an extended class [source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP_TLS):

    class ftplib.FTP_TLS(host='', user='', passwd='', acct='', keyfile=None, certfile=None, context=None, timeout=None, source_address=None)

Comment: I followed this exactly and I'm getting a file not found error. I've checked using os.path.abspath and os.path.isfile but still getting errors when running this script. Whats going on?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

[Paramiko](https://www.paramiko.org/) supports SFTP. I've used it, and I've used Twisted. Both have their place, but you might find it easier to start with Paramiko.

Comment: yepp, paramiko is the way to go (super easy to use), its a bit tricky to find the windows package of pycrypto which is a dependency.

Comment: Thank you.  It took me a while to figure out how to install the package due to the lack of installation instructions in the readme but it was exactly what I needed!

Comment: See http://bitprophet.org/blog/2012/09/29/paramiko-and-ssh/ in which Jeff Forcier explains that ssh is obsolete and paramiko is the way forward.

Comment: There's also http://code.google.com/p/pysftp/ which is based on Paramiko, but easier to use

Comment: Note that Paramiko currently doesn't support authenticating with both multiple methods (e.g. password and private-key). See https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/519.

Comment: [Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 105):

You should check out pysftp https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysftp  it depends on paramiko, but wraps most common use cases to just a few lines of code.

```
import pysftp
import sys

path = './THETARGETDIRECTORY/' + sys.argv[1]    #hard-coded
localpath = sys.argv[1]

host = "THEHOST.com"                    #hard-coded
password = "THEPASSWORD"                #hard-coded
username = "THEUSERNAME"                #hard-coded

with pysftp.Connection(host, username=username, password=password) as sftp:
    sftp.put(localpath, path)

print 'Upload done.'
```

Comment: Vote up for `with` in the example

Comment: `pip install pysftp`

Comment: Is there an option to automatically add new sftp host to known hosts?

Comment: @user443854 yes there is http://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/release_0.2.9/cookbook.html#pysftp-cnopts But I would definitely not recommend that, though you can add another known_host file

Comment: WARNING: Is seems like pysftp is no longer very active.  The link to the issue tracker on their site is broken (says its not setup).  I found found a bug and am trying to figure out the best way to document it and fix it but doesn't seem like it has been updated for over 4 years

Comment: @JDD - Did you ever do anything with this? Maybe your own fork? What was the bug?

Comment: I think it would have been nice if this answer disclosed that the answerer was the author and sole maintainer of the software being recommended. But that user seems to have stopped coming to SO as well as stopped working on `pysftp`.

Comment: paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Bad host key from server

Answer (score 18):

Here is a sample using pysftp and a private key.

```
import pysftp

def upload_file(file_path):

    private_key = "~/.ssh/your-key.pem"  # can use password keyword in Connection instead
    srv = pysftp.Connection(host="your-host", username="user-name", private_key=private_key)
    srv.chdir('/var/web/public_files/media/uploads')  # change directory on remote server
    srv.put(file_path)  # To download a file, replace put with get
    srv.close()  # Close connection
```

pysftp is an easy to use sftp module that utilizes paramiko and pycrypto. It provides a simple interface to sftp.. Other things that you can do with pysftp which are quite useful:

```
data = srv.listdir()  # Get the directory and file listing in a list
srv.get(file_path)  # Download a file from remote server
srv.execute('pwd') # Execute a command on the server
```

More commands and about PySFTP [here](http://pysftp.readthedocs.org/en/release_0.2.8/cookbook.html).

Comment: `srv.get(file_path) # Download a file from remote server` can you explain *where* does it download the file into?

Comment: Did you try the local for you executed from?

Comment: Yeah but where on the file system? Everything goes through successfully but I can't seem to find the file from anywhere.

Comment: Sorry I meant local dir. Try executing the script from your home dir and seeing if the file is there.

Answer (score 17):

If you want easy and simple, you might also want to look at [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/). It's an automated deployment tool like Ruby's Capistrano, but simpler and of course for Python. It's build on top of Paramiko.

You might not want to do 'automated deployment' but Fabric would suit your use case perfectly none the less. To show you how simple Fabric is: the fab file and command for your script would look like this (not tested, but 99% sure it will work):

fab_putfile.py:

```
from fabric.api import *

env.hosts = ['THEHOST.com']
env.user = 'THEUSER'
env.password = 'THEPASSWORD'

def put_file(file):
    put(file, './THETARGETDIRECTORY/') # it's copied into the target directory
```

Then run the file with the fab command:

```
fab -f fab_putfile.py put_file:file=./path/to/my/file
```

And you're done! :)

Comment: I followed this and got the message "Can't find any collection named fabfile!" when i run the python file.

Answer (score 8):

[fsspec](https://filesystem-spec.readthedocs.io/) is a great option for this, it offers a filesystem like implementation of [sftp](https://filesystem-spec.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#fsspec.implementations.sftp.SFTPFileSystem).

```
from fsspec.implementations.sftp import SFTPFileSystem
fs = SFTPFileSystem(host=host, username=username, password=password)

# list a directory
fs.ls("/")

# open a file
with fs.open(file_name) as file:
    content = file.read()
```

Also worth noting that fsspec uses paramiko in the [implementation](https://filesystem-spec.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/fsspec/implementations/sftp.html#SFTPFileSystem).

Answer (score 5):

With RSA Key then refer [here](https://repl.it/@abhijeetbhanjadeo/SFTP-with-RSAKey-1#main.py)

Snippet:

```
import pysftp
import paramiko
from base64 import decodebytes

keydata = b"""AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDl""" 
key = paramiko.RSAKey(data=decodebytes(keydata)) 
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys.add(host, 'ssh-rsa', key)


with pysftp.Connection(host=host, username=username, password=password, cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:   
  with sftp.cd(directory):
    sftp.put(file_to_sent_to_ftp)
```

Answer (score 3):

[Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) can help you with what you are doing, check out their documentation, there are plenty of examples. Also it is a mature product with a big developer/user community behind it.

Comment: [Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 2):

Paramiko is so slow. Use subprocess and shell, here is an example:

```
remote_file_name = "filename"
remotedir = "/remote/dir"
localpath = "/local/file/dir"
    ftp_cmd_p = """
    #!/bin/sh
    lftp -u username,password sftp://ip:port <<EOF
    cd {remotedir}
    lcd {localpath}
    get {filename}
    EOF
    """
subprocess.call(ftp_cmd_p.format(remotedir=remotedir,
                                 localpath=localpath,
                                 filename=remote_file_name 
                                 ), 
                shell=True, stdout=sys.stdout, stderr=sys.stderr)
```

Comment: The question is about "Python", which generally implies sticking within that - especially when there are so many options for doing so.  More importantly though, it says "Platform independent".  I can't say if your answer works faster or not though.  Perhaps?

Comment: Seeing that shabang... yeah this only works on *nix. Not to mention that lftp isn't installed by default on a lot of *nix computers.

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of answers that mention pysftp, so in the event that you want a context manager wrapper around pysftp, here is a solution that is even less code that ends up looking like the following when used

```
path = "sftp://user:p@ssw0rd@test.com/path/to/file.txt"

# Read a file
with open_sftp(path) as f:
    s = f.read() 
print s

# Write to a file
with open_sftp(path, mode='w') as f:
    f.write("Some content.")
```

The (fuller) example: http://www.prschmid.com/2016/09/simple-opensftp-context-manager-for.html

This context manager happens to have auto-retry logic baked in in the event you can't connect the first time around (which surprisingly happens more often than you'd expect in a production environment...)

The context manager gist for `open_sftp`: https://gist.github.com/prschmid/80a19c22012e42d4d6e791c1e4eb8515

Answer (score 1):

[PyFilesystem](https://www.pyfilesystem.org/) with its [sshfs](https://pypi.org/project/fs.sshfs/) is one option. It uses Paramiko under the hood and provides a nicer paltform independent interface on top.

```
import fs

sf = fs.open_fs("sftp://[user[:password]@]host[:port]/[directory]")
sf.makedir('my_dir')
```

or

```
from fs.sshfs import SSHFS
sf = SSHFS(...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generic function that will download any given sftp url to a specified path

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import paramiko

url = 'sftp://username:password@hostname/filepath.txt'

def sftp_download(url, dest):
    url = urlparse(url)
    with paramiko.Transport((url.hostname, 22)) as transport:
        transport.connect(None,url.username,url.password)
        with paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport) as sftp:
            sftp.get(url.path, dest)
```

Call it with

```
sftp_download(url, "/tmp/filepath.txt")
```