# SFTP using ftplib

Tags: python, sftp, ftplib

I need to download a file from a host using SFTP.

Do you know if is it possible to do that using Python ftplib?
I saw [an example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432385/sftp-in-python-platform-independent), but when I try to connect I receive `EOFError`.

I tried this code:

```
import ftplib
ftp = ftplib.FTP()
ftp.connect( "1.2.3.4", "22" )
```

This method returns with an error after long time so I cannot perform a call to login.
I cannot try the constructor `FTP([host[, user[, passwd[, acct[, timeout]]]]])` because 
my port is 22 but `ftplib` default is 21.

If I follow the example

```
ftp = ftplib.FTP("1.2.3.4")
ftp = ftplib.FTP("1.2.3.4","22")
```

I receive a connection refused so I cannot enter any username password. Can you help me? Thank you very much

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As [the question you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432385/sftp-in-python-platform-independent) states, ftplib doesn't support SFTP (which is a transfer protocol over SSH and has nothing to do with FTPS, FTP over SSL). Use the [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432385/sftp-in-python-platform-independent/432403#432403) [Paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/) instead.