# Can i control PSFTP from a Python script?

Tags: python, unix, scripting, ftp, sftp

i want to run and control PSFTP from a Python script in order to get log files from a UNIX box onto my Windows machine.

I can start up PSFTP and log in but when i try to run a command remotely such as 'cd' it isn't recognised by PSFTP and is just run in the terminal when i close PSFTP.

The code which i am trying to run is as follows:

```
import os

os.system("<directory> -l <username> -pw <password>" )
os.system("cd <anotherDirectory>")
```

i was just wondering if this is actually possible. Or if there is a better way to do this in Python.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to run PSFTP as a subprocess and speak directly with the process. `os.system` spawns a separate subshell each time it's invoked so it doesn't work like typing commands sequentially into a command prompt window. Take a look at the documentation for the standard Python `subprocess` module. You should be able to accomplish your goal from there. Alternatively, there are a few Python SSH packages available such as [paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/) and [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com). If you're already happy with PSFTP, I'd definitely stick with trying to make it work first though.

Subprocess module hint:

```
# The following line spawns the psftp process and binds its standard input
# to p.stdin and its standard output to p.stdout
p = subprocess.Popen('psftp -l testuser -pw testpass'.split(), 
                     stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
# Send the 'cd some_directory' command to the process as if a user were 
# typing it at the command line
p.stdin.write('cd some_directory\n')
```

Comment: I've taken a look at subprocess and i can get PSFTP to run but i still can't figure out how to send commands to it?? Any ideas??

Comment: Edited to provide subprocess module example

Answer (score 1):

This has sort of been answered in: [SFTP in Python? (platform independent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432385/sftp-in-python-platform-independent)

http://www.lag.net/paramiko/

The advantage to the pure python approach is that you don't always need psftp installed.

Comment: I've seen this, but i don't want to use a third party library to do this. But thanks for the answer!!