# Python 3.x subprocess - interacting with pipes to call psftp

Tags: python, python-3.x, pipe, subprocess, sftp

I have a script that writes a file to disk and then needs to upload it to a remote server using psftp.

based on some of answers I have seen on this site I have a basic idea of what I want to do but because:

1. My code is written in Python 3.x
2. My code uses a mix of strings and variables in the commands

I have not been successful.

here is my code ( after setting up the variables)

```
connection_string = "" +prog+ "-P "  +port+ "-pw " +passwd+ " " +user+"@"+host

p = subprocess.Popen(connection_string.split(),stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)

sftp_cmd = "put "+upload_file

encoded_cmd = str.encode(sftp_cmd)

p.stdin.write(encoded_cmd)
# I would have rather used p.stdin.write(b'sftp_cmd') to create a buffer from the string but that didn't seem to work either.
```

the code compiles but the file does not get uploaded

1) What am I doing wrong ? :-)

2) How can I see if a connection is made and what command actually goes through ?

3) Is this the best way to call psftp or perhapes I should write a batch file on the fly each time and use the "-b" flag to call it ?

Note. I cannot use any libraries that do not come with the standard Python distro in my code. So I have to use psftp.

referenced answers:

[Can i control PSFTP from a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659395/can-i-control-psftp-from-a-python-script)

[formatting strings for stdin.write() in python 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486947/formatting-strings-for-stdin-write-in-python-3-x)

TIA

Comment: Any specific reason why other libraries like paramiko cannot be used? Also, you may like to have a look at pscp.

Comment: I can't use external libraries due to company restrictions. Scp seems to be blocked on the server (I have no control over it)

Comment: for now I wrote the commands to a file and used psftp -b but would still like to know how to do this in a more python way.

Comment: [Don't use a list argument and `shell=True` together](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15109665/4279) on POSIX systems.

Comment: don't: `klass.method(some_object)`, call `some_object.method()` instead e.g., `sftp_cmd.encode()`.

Answer (score 0):

Drop `shell=True`. If `prog` accept a command on its stdin and you want to get its output as a bytestring then you could use [`subprocess.check_output()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from subprocess import check_output

output = check_output([prog, "-P", port, "-pw", passwd, user + "@" + host],
                      input=("put " + upload_file).encode()) # utf8 filename
```

It raises an exception if `prog` returns a non-zero exit status (It usually means an error).