# MySQL replication and Django FileField

Tags: django, replication, filefield

I have MySQL replication setup, and it replicates nicely the database data. However, I also use FileField and ImageField, and have file loaded onto the FS. I probably will just use rsync to manually replicate this, but is there a better way?

I know of key value storage. But for this project, I am looking to minimize the number of technologies involved and stick with simple options. I've successfully used rsync for this before, but I was wondering if others who have done this have any new cool tools (or even rsync wrappers) that work better.

Your experiences are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't searched to see if anyone has already done this, but you can write your own code in Django to remotely copy the file to your goal server (i.e. SFTP).

Option 1 on this front: create your own Form Field that extends the Image and File field that does this uploading.

Option 2: in your form/view, call some additional function that does the uploading.

Option 3: override something in Django code to handle this automatically for Image and File fields (probably not recommended, unless there is some slick way I'm not thinking of).

Here's info on using SFTP in Python: [SFTP in Python? (platform independent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432385/sftp-in-python-platform-independent)

If you're using something like Amazon's CloudFront or Buckets, then you can use Boto to handle the uploading (I believe): http://aws.amazon.com/code/827?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1 (if not, there are probably other python libraries to help).