# Python script on Windows to access SFTP site

Tags: python, windows, sftp

I need to access `sftp USER@sfile.WEBSITE.com`
and get `20110310statement.pdf` to a directory `$HOME\STATEMENTS` at 3am everyday.

I don't know how to do it in a script giving username and password and figuring the date string on Windows.

I suggest python, but am open to any scripting language.

Any pointers ?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432385/sftp-in-python-platform-independent)? and you can use the `time` module to get the current date and format it however you please.

Comment: +1 Paramiko works nicely.  The only problem I've run into with it is with some oddball SFTP servers not returning the cwd when they should.  If you ever run into problems with relative paths or filenames "not found", give it absolute paths instead.

Comment: @Humble: If this is satisfactory, could you please accept this answer - if not then please give guidance as to any further problems you might be having.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of building something from scratch, you might want to look at using cygwin and rsync or [GoodSync](http://www.goodsync.com/) or [MS SyncToy](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c26efa36-98e0-4ee9-a7c5-98d0592d8c52)