# Python File I/O : Cant create file

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I am executing the following sequence of code :

```
WRITE_MODE = "w"

_output_file = open(path_output_ , WRITE_MODE)

_output_file.write(_out_line_file) : Executed for about 3000 times

_output_file.close()
```

There are no errors/exceptions during execution.

However, no file is generated at path_output_ .

path_output_  : not a local path but remote filer path and there is considerable amount of latency in accessing this path.

Can someone help here ?

Comment: Hope this helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19202314/in-python-how-to-write-a-string-to-a-file-on-a-remote-machine

Comment: Are you trying to write to a mounted drive, or accessing the path directly? What is the contents of `path_output_`? Does the user running the script have access to create files in `path_output_` ?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid : path_output  - C:\Q\reports\......

here, Q is a mounted drive.


When running the script in debug mode (pdb), the output file is being generated. This rules out the permission issue.

Comment: Please give me the path as its written in the source code.

Comment: C:\R\Exports\TEST_PATH\temp\CD01\in_list.txt;

Comment: what difference does this makes ?

Comment: @rakesh.sahu : thanks for replying, but I afraid that the link is not much use.The remote location here is a mounted drive and os Windows.