# How to transfer file from local machine to EC instance in Python?

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-ec2, sftp

There are SFTP client to do the work manually, like this one:
http://comtechies.com/how-to-upload-and-download-files-in-amazon-aws-ec2-instance.html

But, wondering how can it be done using Python in Python Script ?
(apart from creating a batch file...)

EDIT:
As mentionned, in the comments, this one exists :
[SFTP in Python? (platform independent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432385/sftp-in-python-platform-independent)

But, it does not solve the issue of authentification with EC2 Instance.

Thanks, regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SFTP in Python? (platform independent)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432385/sftp-in-python-platform-independent)

Comment: ok, thanks, did not see this one.

Comment: But, It does not solve the problem of idenfication with EC2 instances.

Comment: But that's covered by the link in your question, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you :-

Create the server by creating the reservation :-

```
reservation = conn.run_instances(my_AMI,
        key_name = key,
        instance_type ='c4.xlarge',
        security_group_ids = security_group,
        placement = 'region' )

instance = reservation.instances[0]

print colored("Instance IP: %s" % instance.ip_address, 'yellow')
```

Then later you could scp the file :-

```
instance_IP = instance.ip_address
os.system('scp -i %s %s ubuntu@%s:~/destinationFolder' % (key_path,rgs_tarpath, instance_IP) )
```

Comment: @Tensor, Yes key_path is same as .pem file's path.