# Connecting to an Ubuntu Server with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, ftp, macos-sierra

My goal is to have a basic FTP program written in Python. First, I need to gain more knowledge. My question is, how can I connect to an Ubuntu Server (hosted via VirtualBox) using Python?

I have tried using the page on the [official Python website](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html) but I get an error saying `socket.error: [Errno 61] Connection refused` when using this

```
from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP('jordan@10.0.0.12')
```

[This](http://pastebin.com/WMfy5005) is the output I get when using `ftp - FTP('10.0.0.12')`

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py",
>   line 120, in **init**
>       self.connect(host)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py",
>   line 135, in connect
>       self.sock = socket.create_connection((self.host, self.port), self.timeout)   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py",
>   line 575, in create_connection
>       raise err socket.error: [Errno 61] Connection refused

I can use an FTP program such as Transmit (the same port and on SFTP) on the same machine and it works fine.

Comment: What happens when you try to ftp from the command line the same way? `ftp jordan@10.0.0.12`

Comment: When using the command `ftp jordan@10.0.0.12` from Terminal I get the same error.

Comment: ok so it fails from terminal but works from Transmit right? there may be some default settings, such as passive, or something else, in Transmit that makes it work.

Comment: Yes, it fails in Terminal. (And Python)

Comment: Do you use Transmit on the same machine as the Python code and command-line `ftp`?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The passive mode cannot affect this.

Comment: Is Transmit using the same port? Is it FTP or SFTP?

`PASV` should be set by default in `ftplib`.

Maybe try setting `ftp.set_debuglevel(2)` so we can get some more information?

Comment: How do I get the output of `ftp.set_debuglevel(2)`?

Comment: If `ftp.set_debuglevel(2)` is set before the login attempt, it should automatically output when you `ftp.login()`

Comment: I can't login if I can't even connect to the server...

Comment: In looking at the docs, FTP accepts the user as a separate argument. Try it without `'jordan@'`. If you are able to connect, pass the username as a separate argument. e.g.: `ftp = FTP('10.0.0.12', 'jordan')`

Comment: Same error with both of them. :(

Comment: This is with debuglevel(2)? There should be more information.

Comment: See my edited post.

Comment: Are you saying Transmit connects via SFTP, does it connect via FTP?

Comment: Transmit does not connect via FTP: `Error -157: invalid reply from server` Also, please email me at jordanmbaron12@gmail.com so we don't have a super long thread.

Comment: Python's `ftplib` does not support `SFTP`. It can connect via `FTP with TLS`. You either need to run an `FTP` server on the Ubuntu box or use a solution such as `Paramiko` or `pysftp` to connect to the server in question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432385/sftp-in-python-platform-independent

Comment: I used pysftp and it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python's `ftplib` does not support SFTP, so using [PySFTP](http://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/release_0.2.8/cookbook.html) would work.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is using paramiko.