# Dealing with remote folders while using the os module in a python code?

Tags: python, sftp

I have written a small program that uses the `os` module extensively especially `os.walk`, `os.remove` etc. For example,

```
def dump_folder(source, destination):
    """
    """
    # uses os.walk, shutil.move

def encrypt_folder(folder, recipient):
    """
    """
    # uses os.walk, os.remove
```

Now, I would like to extend this program to support `SFTP` folders.

Do I need to mount the folders locally to make `os.*` work? For example, in Windows, I could use `win32net` and do something like:

```
try:
    win32wnet.WNetAddConnection2(...drive, remote...)                                
except:
    pass
```

If I am going to use a tool like `paramiko`, can I make it work with the same code without worrying about the details which `os.walk`, `os.remove`, `shutil.move` provides? If I can't, then I will have to rewrite the program quite a bit which is not something I want.

PS: The goal of this question is to find out how to use the **same code** to work with **remote folders**. Tools like `paramiko` deals with implementation details (like where is the file etc) so we will have to re-write the program . The idea of mounting remote file locally and ability to use `os` is really nice and powerful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SFTP in Python? (platform independent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432385/sftp-in-python-platform-independent)

Comment: @Peter Wood, I think it is not a complete duplicate as I am not asking about `paramiko` per se. I would like to use the same code for remote access! That is the goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sorry to disappoint you, but the situation is indeed exactly as you describe in your question:

Yes, you do need to mount your remote directory if you want to use `os.walk`, `os.remove`, `shutil.move`, etc.

If you use a specialized SFTP library such as `paramiko` (or calling ssh/sftp via the `subprocess` module), you'll have to implement the functionaliy of `os.walk` on your own.

By the way, if you decide to implement your own `os.walk` on top of `paramiko`, you might want to contribute that function back to `paramiko`, as it may be helpful for other users of that library, too.

Answer (score 1):

As the @vog's answer says already, you cannot use `os.*` functions for SFTP, unless you mount a remote filesystem to a local one.

---

The only other way is to use some Python SFTP client library.

There's [pysftp library](https://pypi.org/project/pysftp/), which is a more Pytonish wrapper around Paramiko library. And pysftp has  [`walktree` method](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pysftp.html#pysftp.Connection.walktree):

```
walktree(remotepath, fcallback, dcallback, ucallback, recurse=True)
```