# Python - not sure if I'm connecting via FTP or SFTP to a server

Tags: python, ftp, sftp, urllib2

I'm using `urllib` to make a request to a server.

When the URL has the format `ftp://ftp.piplatam.com//...`, it runs OK.

When the URL has the format `ftp://sftp.piplatam.com//...`, it runs OK.

When the URL has the format `sftp://sftp.piplatam.com//...`, it fails. Error: `'<class urllib2.URLError>' and message '<urlopen error unknown url type: sftp>'`

Why does this happen? Also, if I run the request the second way, am I using FTP or SFTP?

Comment: Isn't the error message clear? `urllib` doesn't know how to implement the `sftp:` protocol.

Comment: So how can I make a sftp request if urllib can't do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432385/sftp-in-python-platform-independent