# Automated transfer of files to an SFTP - SPSS Modeler / PS Clem

Tags: excel, automation, sftp, file-transfer, spss-modeler

We currently use SPSS Modeler for our analytics and output to excel files for reporting. We automate the running of modeler streams with PS Clementine.

We do have access to SQL server tables within Modeler via ODBC connections.

What I need to do is to automate sending some of the outputs created to an SFTP daily (Filezilla). The outputs currently sit in a Onedrive location.

Ideally I'd like to be able to do some checks on the file I.e how many rows of data held etc. If the checks pass or fail I'd like to then email a distribution list to either advise them to investigate or to advise the file has been transferred to the SFTP successfully.

I've done this using a combination of SAS Cloud / Hadoop/  SAS on prem / Globalscape before.

Is there a solution that suits SPSS modeler/ PS Clementine?

I've searched the forum regarding the following but haven't found a relevant solution for my set up so any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: And comments / help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible out-of-the-box.

However, I think the following workaround should be possible (assuming SPSS modeler has enough privileges in your environment): You could either use a [Python for Spark](https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/wsd/nodes/extension_pyspark_api.html?locale=en) export node or the [SPSS Modeler Scripting API](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/spss-modeler/saas?topic=automation-scripting-language) to check the data and use [python for the sftp transfer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432385/sftp-in-python-platform-independent).

We use python to extend the functionality of SPSS Modeler all the time with great success.